# Proper way to repeat an operation firing off an event stream

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava, so I'm still trying to get my head around it. I've got an `Observable` representing a stream of button clicks, so it's hot. Every time that button is clicked, I want to do some I/O. If it fails, I want to repeat and try to do that I/O again, until it succeeds. This seems like a great opportunity to use `retry()` or `repeat()`, but those only work on hot observables, and not cold.

Here's some pseudocode to get at what I'm trying to do:

```
buttonRequests
   .map(actionEvent -> doIO())
   .repeatAboveIfFailedUntilIOSucceeds()
   .subscribe(...);
```

I've considered using `flatMap` to duplicate the event and than using `skip` to ignore the remaining ones if it succeeds, but that won't cleanly get me an indeterminate number of attempts.

What would be the right way to think about this?

Comment: Do you want to repeat a failed action for each button-click, until it succeeds? What should happen if it is retrying and a new flighes in?

Comment: Yes, I would retry the action for each button click until it succeeds. I'd disable the button to keep it from being reclicked while that's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the test. On every event a new IO-Request will be fired. Switch-Map is like Flat-Map, but it will unsubscribe from the recent subscription, when a new upstream-event comes in. Flat-Map would just start a new one, if you are working with concurrency. So lets assume your hot observable fired an event and the flatMap start executing your IO work on another thread (subscribeOn). If another event comes in, while the last one is still executing, it will start executing another IO-task. Switch-Map will unsubscribe from the last one and start one for the current event. Lets have a look at the retry()-operator. Retry will just re-subscribe to the observable provided by 'ioWorkWrapped' until the observable finishes with onComplete. This is probably very dangerous, because imagine it will fail on every try. It would spin forever. It is recommended to use 'exponential-backoff' and provide a back-up observable fails after X tries. For the usage of 'retryWhen' please have a look at this excellent book[: Reactive Programming with RxJava](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do)

```
public class LibraryTest {
    private AtomicInteger idx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        idx = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.just(1)
                .switchMap(integer -> ioWorkWrapped()
                        .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("Something went wrong."))
                        .retry()
                );

        stringObservable.test()
                .await()
                .assertResult("value");


    }

    private Observable<String> ioWorkWrapped() {
        return Observable.defer(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500); // IO Work
                if (idx.getAndIncrement() < 5) { // for testing...
                    return Observable.error(new IllegalStateException("Wurst"));
                }
                return Observable.just("value");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return Observable.error(ex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. I've been able to integrate this idea into my code; I also learned a lot working through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the operator `retryWhen` in case your I/O operation fail you can throw a Runnable exception that is checked in the operator. And in case is that type of Exception you retry.

In this example we will retry for 4 times. But that condition it could be changed by the type of throwable that we receive.

```
int count=0;

@Test
public void retryWhenConnectionError() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(null)
            .map(connection -> {
                System.out.println("Trying to open connection");
                connection.toString();
                return connection;
            })
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                            .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) :
                                    Observable.just(null).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)),
                    Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/errors/ObservableExceptions.java

Comment: Thank youI I found another response above that better fit my needs, but I spent some time with this one as well and it helped improve my understanding.